# Windows 10 Build 10122 Live Tiles Disabled

Tags: start-menu, windows-10-preview, live-tiles

[image]

As you can see the majority of my "live" tiles are disabled. I click, and nothing happens. At first I thought it was automatically downloading them, but after some time nothing changes. The rest of the apps have the line under them (look at Alarm & Clock on the left), but do not seem to start downloading. I cannot open the Windows Store (like in Windows 8) to download them because I don't have it downloaded! Is this a bug or normal? Perhaps a way to reset this...

Comment: Yes;  You reset it by reinstalling Windows 10.  You can wait for a future build to perhaps fix it.  You can report the problem perhaps, there is a work around, and somebody will make a comment on your feedback report.  Your problems are likely connected to the fact you don't have Windows Store installed for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to fix it. If you get either **blank tiles** or **tiles that do not load** (make sure you give it time), then you have a corrupt user account. Backup your user data and follow the steps:

1. Under *Account Settings* -> *Family & other users*, add a temporary account. I suggest a local account to make it easier. Make sure you click the account again to change the setting to Administrator.
2. Log in with that account, go back to *Account Settings* and delete your original account.
3. Instead of updating your account to a Microsoft Account, add a new Microsoft Account under *Family and other users*.
4. Your new account should be created once you sign out and sign in. Hopefully everything loads correctly.
5. Run -> **netplwiz**. Delete your temporary account there. This somehow keeps some core files from getting deleted, hence, circumventing the bug.

This bug does exist for sure in 10122 and 10074. Not sure how far back it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Wonky behavior comes with the territory in Windows 10 beta. Each build has it own cute little "personality quirks". I'm running build 10122 on three different machines and each behaves differently. One machine refused to load the Live Tiles but the others were fine.
It's beta, after all.....

Comment: I just reinstalled 10074 and I have no tiles. Apparently that particular issue is inherited. I tried creating a local user (as administrator), loggin out and re-adding the MS account... then another problem will pop up.